# Can the value of a polynomial with rational a variable be an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Is there a way to find if the value of the function

$f(g,x,y)=y^3 g^4+4g^3 xy^2+6g^2 x^2 y+4gx^3$ can ever be an integer,

where

$x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, $x>>y$

$g\in\mathbb{Q}$, $0<g<1$

Thank you.

Comment: You always can. If $g=p/q$ and $y=q^2, x=qN$, where $N$ is a large integer. Or do you mean if given $x,y$ you can find $g$?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I wonder if this is the only possible solution though.